# UWP dates aren't respecting local region's date format

Tags: uwp

Even with a blank new UWP, the UWP app won't respect regional date settings. It displays dates in United States format even though my settings are set to Australia.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out UWP apps only respect the **language** settings and ignore region settings (which makes no sense to users). If you change your language to English (Australian), the dates are correctly displayed within UWP.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the `Date` of the `DatePicker` to local time.

```cs
var now = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();
datePicker.Date = now;
```

Best regards.